lookupObject.getValue is not a function
I have a function that retrieves the value of a lookup Object.
var lookupObject = formContext.getAttribute("attributename");
var selectedRecord = lookupObject.getValue();

It's throwing the error that lookupObject.getValue() is not a function.

Sorry @jeremy-denis the issue seems to be with this constants object. So I am retrieving "attributename" using this object and it's not returning any value.

I rolled back your latest question edit. Please do not change the context of a question, by editing it into something completely different than it was about before. If you have a new topic, ask a new question.

getAttribute returns a string, why are you calling getValue() on it?

the reason is that formContext.getAttribute("attributename") is not returning an Object.
It is not returning an Object because the field attributename is not present inside the model-driven app form where you attached the script.

Correct! Sorry I figured out by myself and updated the quetion before seeing your answer. Can you please take a look at the updated question? Thank You.

The update makes this answer redundant.
